# Facebook webhook IP address not in the docs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating the webhook to my computer server. According to the official docs. It says the following command will provide me `CIDR` of them.

[Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/)

```
whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route
```

But when I implement. I always got another Facebook IP addresses which are not in the list.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736642/facebook-messenger-webhook-source-ip-whitelist) I am aware that it frequently changed. But it should not out of the list in 10 seconds.

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs . Which IP do you get the request from?

Comment: @WizKid It is here. https://www.abuseipdb.com/whois/173.252.84.52
My colleague has issued the ticket already, but still no response. I think it is working hour is different from my timezone. Anyway he is issuing again with IP address included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got new knowledge today!
`Nginx`, `Docker`, `Django` through the way until reach my code variable
`REMOTE_ATTR` got mutated by someone in the line. Then I add new reference `X-Real-IP` with the same variable and then observe my code again.

```
location / {
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header           Host $host;
        proxy_pass                 http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
}
```

And someone again mutate the variable name from `X-Real-IP` to `HTTP_X_REAL_IP`. Finally my `WebhookPermission` must be this

```
import logging

from rest_framework import permissions

from poinkbackend.apps.socials.utils import check_whitelist

logger = logging.getLogger('django')


class WebhookPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        ip_addr = request.META['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']
        logger.info(f'{ip_addr} inbound a webhook')
        logger.info(f'{request.META}')
        return check_whitelist(ip_addr)
```